# WCF : How to remove http headers like aspnet version, server etc from WCF service calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have requirement where in for security reason I am not supposed to disclose response headers like server, asp.net version etc.

How can I restrict these headers when calls are made for WCF services.

I have already tried the below config settings but works fine for aspx page calls but not for WCF service calls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="Server" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks,
Mahantesh M. B.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into IIS and select your Site where your webservice is running on, in the IIS section there is a button called HTTP Response Headers, click on it and remove the headers

following your comment you can try to add a message inspector

```
public class RemoveHeaders: IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request,
        IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

        var httpCtx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpCtx != null)
        {
            httpCtx.Response.Headers.Remove(HttpResponseHeader.Server.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chino, This step I have already tried. When I get into the response headers in IIS, it is initially contain nothing. I added new headers and made it blank. It works fine but for WCF and web service calls it still continues to display the IIS and asp.net version :(